# Help with first order linear PDE with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following pde:

$2y\cdot \partial_x u(x,y)-3x\cdot\partial_yu(x,y)=0$
and

$u(x,x)=e^{x^2}$

Without the initial condition I got the following result:

$\frac{1}{4}(2y^2+3x^2)=C$

How do I get the solution for the Cauchy-problem?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic curves would be $3x^2+2y^2 = C$. Hence, $u(x,y) = f(3x^2+2y^2)$ and $u(x,x) = f(5x^2) = e^{x^2}$. Hence, $f(x) = e^{x/5}$ and $u(x,y) = e^{\frac{3x^2+2y^2}{5}}$

Comment: Thanks! Is there any method to find $f(x)$ from $f(5x^2)$?

Comment: Just replace $x$ with $\sqrt{(\frac{x}{5})}$ in $f(5x^2)$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\totald{x}{t}=2y\,,\ \totald{y}{t}=-3x\ \imp\ 2y\,\totald{y}{x} + 3x=0
     \ \imp\ x^{2} + {2 \over 3}\,y^{2} = \mbox{constant}}$.

> \begin{align}
> \,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}&=\fermi\pars{x^{2} + {2 \over 3}\,y^{2}}\ \imp\
> \expo{x^{2}}=\,{\rm u}\pars{x,x}=\fermi\pars{{5 \over 3}\,x^{2}}\
> \imp\ \fermi\pars{t}=\exp\pars{{3 \over 5}\,t}
> \\[5mm]&\imp\
> \color{#66f}{\large\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}
> =\exp\pars{{3 \over 5}\,\bracks{x^{2} + {2 \over 3}\,y^{2}}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\exp\pars{3x^{2} + 2y^{2} \over 5}}
> \end{align}

Let's check it:
\begin{align}
2y\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}{x}&
=2y\,\exp\pars{3x^{2} + 2y^{2} \over 5}\,{6x \over 5}
={12xy \over 5}\,\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
\\[5mm]3x\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}{x}&
=3x\,\exp\pars{3x^{2} + 2y^{2} \over 5}\,{4y \over 5}
={12xy \over 5}\,\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
\\[5mm]\imp&\ 2y\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}{x}
-3x\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}{x} = 0\ \mbox{and}\
\left.\exp\pars{3x^{2} + 2y^{2} \over 5}\right\vert_{\, y\ =\ x} = \exp\pars{x^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but, how do I get $u(x,x)=e^{x^2}$ from this?

Comment: @kanbhold I did some corrections. Please check them. Thanks.